# Promises on cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm writing a cloud code function for run many task after delete an object. 
How can I do this cleanly and without nesting?

You can run tasks in parallel or it is better to have them sequentially? If so, how?

This is my code, can you help me to clean/change?

```
Parse.Cloud.afterDelete("Photo", function(request) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  //delete all related activities
  var queryAct = new Parse.Query("Activity");
  queryAct.equalTo("photo",{
    __type: "Pointer",
    className: "Photo",
    objectId: request.object.id
  });
  queryAct.limit(1000);
  queryAct.find({
    success: function(activities) {
      Parse.Object.destroyAll(activities, {
        success: function() {
          //delete all related hashtags
          var queryTags = new Parse.Query("hashTags");
          queryTags.equalTo("photo",{
            __type: "Pointer",
            className: "Photo",
            objectId: request.object.id
          });
          queryTags.limit(1000);
          queryTags.find({
            success: function(hashtags) {
              Parse.Object.destroyAll(hashtags, {
                success: function() {},
                 error: function(error) {
                  console.error("Error deleting related hashtags " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
                }
              });
            },
            error: function(error){
              console.error("Error finding related hashtags " + error.code + ": " + error.message); 
            }
          });
        },
        error: function(error) {
          console.error("Error deleting related activities " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
        }
      });
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.error("Error finding related activities " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here find.then.delete is a series of tasks in a row. However, you can delete  your `hastags` and `activities` in parallel since they don't seem to be dependent. Please check [promises guide](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises) for more info.
Your code can be shortened as below:

```
var Photo = Parse.Object.extend("Photo");

Parse.Cloud.afterDelete("Photo", function(request) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  var photo = Photo.createWithoutData(request.object.id);

  var queryAct = new Parse.Query("Activity");
  queryAct.equalTo("photo", photo);
  queryAct.limit(1000);
  var promiseForActivities = queryAct.find().then(function (activities) {
    return Parse.Object.destroyAll(activities);
  });

  var queryTags = new Parse.Query("hashTags");
  queryTags.equalTo("photo", photo);
  queryTags.limit(1000);
  var promiseForHashtags = queryTags.find().then(function (hashtags) {
    return Parse.Object.destroyAll(hashtags);
  });

  return Parse.Promise.when([promiseForActivities, promiseForHashtags]).then(function () {
    console.log("Done");
  }, function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
});
```

Note that you don't need to create your own pointer objects like:

```
{
  __type: "Pointer",
  className: "Photo",
  objectId: "someId"
}
```

Rather you can use [createWithoutData](http://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Object.html#.createWithoutData) which is a shortcut for:

```
var Photo = Parse.Object.extend("Photo");
var p = new Photo();
p.id = "someId";
```

I also think that it could be enough to pass the `request.object` directly,  like `queryAct.equalTo("photo", request.object);`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, very useful!
I have a question: in the final step, You could explain .then after .when? the done is not defined, as I call it?

Comment: Fixed it now, it is just a log saying "Done" when both promises are finished