# Query Session class with cloud code Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I am trying to send a push notification using a user's id. I have already tested sending with installationId, querying the _Installation class, but i would like to query the session class of the user pointer, to then turn around and query the installation class.

My problem is lying in the restrictions of querying the session class. I have successfully used createWithoutData() found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29927344/6481734), and I know it is working because i can output that user. However, even after using the master key found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24662281/6481734), the results are always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general practise for sending Push Notification to specific user is that you will store pointer to User in Installation class... for example when user register do this

**Swift**

```
if let installation = PFInstallation.current() {
    installation["user_id"] = PFUser.current()!
    installation.saveInBackground()
}
```

**Cloudcode**

```
      var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
      pushQuery.equalTo('user_id', tarUser);
      pushQuery.exists("deviceToken");
      pushQuery.limit(1); // in case there are more Installation with the user ID, use only the latest
      pushQuery.descending("createdAt");
      Parse.Push.send({
        where: pushQuery, // Set our Installation query
        data: {
          alert: "Some push text"
        }
      }, {
      success: function() {
        // Push was successful
        response.success();

      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error);
        response.error(error);
      },
       useMasterKey: true 
    });
```

if I remember correctly you have to query the pointer in Cloud code with pointer structure, like this

```
var tarUser = { 
  __type: 'Pointer',
  className: '_User',
  objectId: 'insertObjectIDHere'
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I will mark your answer as correct for future reference , but I have chosen not to do that because I want single device log in, which would mean extensive code when logging out another device.

Comment: what does single device login even means?

Comment: If you are familiar with snapchat, if you log into another device, all other sessions are deleted for that user.

Comment: i see... well you can create a condition in all your queries that you want always the latest row in database, and even if the user would have more sessions only the last one will be used.... or as you mentioned you can check for every new row if it not previously exist and if yes delete the old ones....